# How can I allow users to create private data in Firebase for Android?

Tags: android, firebase

I want to make an online password saver app for Android using Firebase.  Firebase's docs tell me about authentication and CRUD methods, but I can't find anything on allowing users to create private data only accessible by them.  How can I do this? Or where can I find this information?

Answer (score 6):

The Firebase Database has a flexible rules-based security model. See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) for all details.

When you combine it with Firebase Authentication, you'll be able to do [user based authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/database/user-security).

The simplest possible example from that doc:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($uid)
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I'd recommend reading that documentation for full details.

Comment: Also see this great video session presented in google io may 2016 titled "The key to firebase security"  https://youtu.be/PUBnlbjZFAI

Answer (score 1):

You can use rules to allow users to store private data, after authenticate the user, create a private path starting with the unique user id.
Suppose you have the following json structure

```
{
  "users" : {
    "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee" : {
        //private data of user with unique id "aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee"
    },
    "ffffffff-gggg-hhhh-iiii-kkkkkkkkkkkk" : {
        //private data of user with unique id "ffffffff-gggg-hhhh-iiii-kkkkkkkkkkkk"
    }
  }
}
```

You must allow only the right user to read and write the folder, even create the path if it doesn’t exist.
The rules can be as follow:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
      ".write": "newData.hasChild(auth.uid)", //you can write only if you put your data inside a path starting with your id
      "$uid":{
        ".read":"$uid == auth.uid" //only the right user can read the data
      }
    }
  }
}
```